# Redirect to an anchor tag in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

Is it possible to position a result page (in Struts2) to an anchor tag on a JSP ?

I've tried:

```
<result>ResultPage.jsp#myAnchor</result>
```

and things like:

```
<result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">ResultAction.action#myAnchor</param>
        <param name="namespace">/</param>
</result>
```

but nothing like this seems to work. I've seen suggestions based on JavaScript, would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Somehow I missed these in my research :

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/redirect-result.html

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html

Comment: I'm still not clear about this. I tried type="redirect" and got an error rendering the resultant JSP because of an inclusion of the struts-dojo-tags <sx:head/> tag - which I think I understand why. However, when I try the type="redirectAction", I don't see how this works. If I forward to another action, that action's return value seems to supercede/replace my initial value, and attempt to specify an anchor parameter seems lost.

Comment: It will be nice that you put the correct answer to this question once you know it :)

Comment: And I WILL post an answer once I figure it out.

Comment: RedirectAction result type, means redirect to an action... I would start with the plain redirect result type... you should be able to redirect to any resource on the web. The client handles the issues of looking up the anchor all you have to worry about is presenting the correct string for the browser to do its thing and the redirect result type is perfect for that.

Comment: Sorry @ben_979, I thought you found the answer since I didn't read your second comment.

Comment: @Quaternion - I have tried "redirect". In my target JSP, I use the struts-dojo-tags and when it goes to render that page, it throws an error because there is no longer an active Struts session.  I'm trying to figure out how to use a "redirectAction", since one of the parameters is "anchor", but I can't figure out how that value can ever be used.

Comment: I don't understand what dojo tags have to do with anything, they are deprecated and in general should be avoided.

Comment: @Quaternion I'm using <%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx" %> because I want to use the datetimepicker. If I use 'redirect', the jsp page throws a "The Struts dispatcher cannot be found. " error at the <sx:head/> tag.

Comment: Use one of the many excellent jquery date time pickers... Why not look at the officially supported jquery ui datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Switched to the jquery datepicker. This didn't help my original problem, although I much prefer this datepicker implementation. Further investigation showed that this was not a struts problem at all, it was a CSS problem. I'm using a tabbed page, and the anchors I was trying to reach were denoting the tabs. I found out that there are complexities to this outside of using struts. I rebuilt my pages using a different structure and different CSS and I can now achieve what I was after (although I am no longer redirecting to anchors). Thanks to all posters for their suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

check this...

```
<result type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">ResultAction.action</param>
    <param name="namespace">/</param>
    <param name="anchor">myAnchor</param>
</result>
```

[Doc: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html)

Happy Code !

Comment: This is exactly what I've tried that fails with the struts-dojo-tags